# Why can't ONE Iperf thread fill the CPU？

Tags: iperf

I'm running iperf2 on ubuntu18.04 and trying to test the max bandwidth with one CPU. My topology is client(with CX5 100G nic)->switch(100G)->server(with CX5 100G nic).

Unfortunately, the speed is only 30Gbps. Then I do a loopback test, the speed is 60Gbps and the cpu usage is 100%. What should I do?

```
Binding to local address 10.0.0.2
Write buffer size:  128 KByte
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.0.0.2 port 42749 connected with 10.0.0.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 0.00-1.00 sec  3.71 GBytes  31.9 Gbits/sec  30379/0          0     6025K/354 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 1.00-2.00 sec  3.59 GBytes  30.8 Gbits/sec  29415/0          0     6684K/271 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 2.00-3.00 sec  3.63 GBytes  31.2 Gbits/sec  29712/0          0     7407K/399 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 3.00-4.00 sec  3.71 GBytes  31.8 Gbits/sec  30359/0          0     8285K/399 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 4.00-5.00 sec  3.73 GBytes  32.0 Gbits/sec  30520/0          0     8285K/328 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 5.00-6.00 sec  3.77 GBytes  32.4 Gbits/sec  30911/0          0     8285K/378 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 6.00-7.00 sec  3.77 GBytes  32.4 Gbits/sec  30920/0          0     8285K/384 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 7.00-8.00 sec  3.74 GBytes  32.1 Gbits/sec  30646/0          0     8285K/325 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 8.00-9.00 sec  3.77 GBytes  32.4 Gbits/sec  30917/0          0     8285K/334 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 9.00-10.00 sec  3.72 GBytes  32.0 Gbits/sec  30503/0          0     8285K/278 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 0.00-10.00 sec  37.1 GBytes  31.9 Gbits/sec  304286/0          0     8285K/278 us
```

```
Binding to local address 10.0.0.2
Write buffer size:  128 KByte
TCP window size: 2.50 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.0.0.2 port 37687 connected with 10.0.0.2 port 5001
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 0.00-1.00 sec  3.85 GBytes  33.1 Gbits/sec  31562/0          0     1087K/41 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 1.00-2.00 sec  5.82 GBytes  50.0 Gbits/sec  47638/0          0     1087K/20 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 2.00-3.00 sec  7.65 GBytes  65.7 Gbits/sec  62644/0          0     1087K/19 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 3.00-4.00 sec  7.46 GBytes  64.1 Gbits/sec  61140/0          0     1342K/19 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 4.00-5.00 sec  7.66 GBytes  65.8 Gbits/sec  62716/0          0     1342K/19 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 5.00-6.00 sec  7.60 GBytes  65.3 Gbits/sec  62231/0          0     1342K/21 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 6.00-7.00 sec  7.67 GBytes  65.9 Gbits/sec  62833/0          0     1342K/17 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 7.00-8.00 sec  7.71 GBytes  66.2 Gbits/sec  63134/0          0     1342K/19 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 8.00-9.00 sec  7.73 GBytes  66.4 Gbits/sec  63291/0          0     1342K/19 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 9.00-10.00 sec  7.73 GBytes  66.4 Gbits/sec  63311/0          0     2110K/44 us
[ ID] Interval        Transfer    Bandwidth       Write/Err  Rtry    Cwnd/RTT
[  3] 0.00-10.00 sec  70.9 GBytes  60.9 Gbits/sec  580508/0          0     2110K/44 us
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your loopback test will likely have a much larger packet size than your over-the-network test.  That will mean TCP needs to to fewer trips up/down the protocol stack to transfer a given quantity of data.

For another, your loopback test will not include any of the overhead for the driver of your 100G NIC.

Also, one of the many limits to the performance of a TCP connection is:

Throughput <= WindowSize / RoundTripTime

and while the round-trip time on your small 100G setup may be small, they are still longer than loopback, and you are trying for a throughput which is quite large, so the default limits for the TCP window size of your stack may be impeding getting higher throughput.